# So i have a UIImage and I want it so when I click on it, it will change to a different image

Tags: swift

```
@IBOutlet weak var BlueBalloon: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var GreenBalloon: UIImageView!
```

So I've put the image in as a variable, i just want to know where do i go from here?

Comment: Don't declare properties with capital letter https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#naming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create @IBAction

```
@IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"Your image name here"), for: .normal)
}
```